# Question about a common explanation of convergence in probability vs almost-sure convergence

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm far from the only person to have issues grasping the difference between convergence in probability ($\lim_{n\to\infty}[\Pr(|X_{n}-Y|>E)]=0$ for any $E>0$) and the stronger almost-sure convergence ($\Pr(\lim_{n\to\infty}[X_{n}]=Y)=1$). A common layman's explanation of the difference is as follows: in the sequence of $X_{n}$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$, almost-sure convergence suggests that there is a finite $N$ such that $X_{n}=Y$ for all $n\ge N$, while convergence in probability suggests that there might be a non-zero probability that $X_{n}$ deviates from $Y$ for all finite $n$, though this probability does at least converge to zero.

The explanation of the convergence in probability seems consistent with its formal statement. However, the explanation of almost-sure convergence seems to be stronger than the formal statement which deals only with the limit. On the other hand, if almost-sure convergence does NOT imply that, then I fail to see the distinction from convergence in probability.

Comment: 'there exists a finite N such that $X_n=y$ for all $n \geq N$' is totally wrong. Kolomogorov modelled probability theory using measure theory and this model is the basis of all modern probability theory. Understanding this subject requires an equal dose of technical measure theoretic arguments and probabilistic intuition. The distinction between almost sure convergence and convergence in probability is technical and anyone who attempts to give an intuitive explanation will come up with something as ridiculous as the one quoted above.

Comment: I agree with Kavi. I'm not sure why those explanations are claimed to be common, but they're incorrect, and I think they're not fixable.

Comment: So it really is just BS then

Comment: I said they were common because I encountered the explanation or some variation of it repeatedly. It's even on the wikipedia page for Convergence of Random Variables.